# Deep Property Binding with Caliburn Micro issues

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm just not figuring out what I am doing wrong. I'm trying to use Caliburn Micro on a WPF app(4.5).  Trying to follow MVVM for what it's worth.

My VM has property of Services and Authorization.  Authorization has a property of SelectedService.  I have named my control `x:Name=Services` and when I populate the Services property they show up in the RadGridView but when you select an Item in the RadGridView it doesn't Bind the `SelectedItem` back to my `SelectedService` property.  Is it because the Services property is at one level and the `SelectedService` is a level deeper, `Authorizations.SelectedService`?

Below is as much of my code as I dared post without flooding the post.  Hopefully it's enough.

I feel like I'm so close to "getting" Caliburn Micro and MVVM in general....

```
public class Authorization:BindableBase
{
    public int ID
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set
        {
            this.id = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Service SelectedService
    {
        get { return this.selectedService; }
        set
        {
            this.selectedService = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Member ActiveMember
    {
        get { return this.activeMember; }
        set
        {
            this.activeMember = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And then CreateAuthViewModel has that Model and also a property for populating the possible choices called Services:

```
[Export(typeof(IScreen))]
public class CreateAuthViewModel : Screen, IHandle<MessageNotifier>
{     
    public Authorization Authorization
    {
        get { return this.authorization; }
        set
        {
            this.authorization = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    public BindableCollection<Service> Services
    {
        get { return services; }
        set
        {
            services = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
```

And finally my View, CreateAuthView:

```
<UserControl x:Name="CreateAuthUserControl"
             x:Class="Green.Views.CreateAuthView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
  <telerik:RadExpander>
    <StackPanel>
      <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Services"
                           IsReadOnly="True"
                           SelectionMode="Extended"
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
      <telerik:RadDataPager x:Name="ServicesDataPager"
                            PageSize="10"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=Services}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </telerik:RadExpander>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Where in your view is your Authorization_SelectedService named control?

Comment: There isn't one in the View.  I had thought, with Combobox and Datagrid, that the convention was that it would Bind the `x:Name` to the matching property on the VM for the itemsource and look for a property on the VM called "Selected, Active, or Single" and the same name as the 1st property.  That's what I'm trying to get it to do.  It never sets the SelectedItem of the Datagrid to my `Authorization.SelectedItem` property.

Comment: What DataGrid? You have a RadGridView and a RadDataPager. I can't see anything else in the view.

Comment: Sorry, slip of the tongue, I meant RadGridView.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Telerik conventions out of the box as this would require a dependency on the Telerik controls. You can have a look at writing your own [conventions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation), or using the [Caliburn.Micro.Telerik](https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik) project which is available as a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/).

Comment: I'm so sorry, I should have been clearer.  I am using the Caliburn.Micro.Telerik conventions.  It has conventions for the RadGridView but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Well it's not a lot to go on. Do you actually populate the Services property? Does your grid view have items in it at all that are blank? Do you get any binding errors in your Output window when debugging? Your question mentions x:Name=Authorization_SelectedService but this is nowhere to be seen in your view.

Comment: Sorry, I will try and be clearer.  I will edit my post directly.  Thank you so much for trying to help me.